# HTML Markup Generator from Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a html template generator sort of like [this](http://www.quackit.com/html/html_generators/html_code_generator.cfm). It's going to have specific style and markup so all it really has to do is take the inputs from the form and place them in the "template" and output as text for easy copy/paste. I was wondering if there is an easier way to make this, like using jQuery. Open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a selection of methods for dealing with the DOM that could come in useful for creating HTML markup from a form. It also has a few methods specific to forms themselves, if that suits your purposes.

Check out the [API for Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). There are a variety of methods you may find useful.

Since you are constructing HTML with form values, the [.wrap() method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) could be quite valuable to surround content with the inputted tags, ids, and classes, which could be styled with a externally linked CSS file. See also the .wrapAll() and .wrapInner().

You may find the .html() method interesting  as well for grabbing the contents of any element. It is somewhat the reverse of what you need but it could come in handy.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand this manipulates what's in the DOM. How would I output that as text for copy/paste?

Comment: If you are trying to display the HTML output like the example, you could surround generated / manipulated HTML into a [<textarea> tag](http://www.dialme.com/m/articles/view/How-to-Render-and-Output-HTML-as-Text). The generated HTML would be in the page DOM, but I don't think that's really a problem, as you are going to display it anyway.

Comment: Ok worked that part out, and what if I want to get text from a input tag? Do I have to "action=post" the form first? Because the information in the input tag isn't in the DOM yet.

Comment: If you need to grab text or another value from a form, check the [.val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/). As for where to put the information, there are a variety of ways you could go about this. Personally, I would have a hidden div already in the DOM that you add to, and once the javascript is processed you could show that div with the text area around your generated HTML.

Comment: And lets say someone doesn't fill in a certain form input, and the value would end up to be "[object HTMLInputElement]". Best thing to do would be make an "if" input is empty then ignore it type of statement?

Comment: You should probably search or open a new question if you want to piece together the script. I imagine if/else would work fine, or possibly default blank values.